# LMEM for repeated measures: nested random, fixed, or both?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I have a dataset on greenhouse gas emissions from 5 different sites under the same treatment, sampled in biweekly intervals over one year.

So what I have is:

```
- 4 site samples each were assigned to two treatment groups
- Measurements of each site were taken on multiple days during the year
- Various soil chemical analyses for each site, plus environmental variables
```

In my world:

```
-  Site (random) is nested within treatment (random, fixed?)
-  Soil chemistry and environmental variable data are random effects
```

BUT:

1. How to deal with treatment? It could be a random effect since the samples were placed in groups according to treatments (agricultural set-up), but it is clearly also a fixed effect.
   Further, there will be a site:treatment interaction. Should it be only fixed? Should site be nested in treatment (random)? Or both?
2. How to integrate day of sampling? Should it also be fixed and included in the nested structure? If yes, where? When I tried date/treatment/site, I only received an error.

FURTHER:
The treatment is the manipulation of the water table. So even though it was controlled, there were fluctuations due to environmental variables. So in the data, there exists treatment as a column, but also the water table as measured on the sampling occassions.

Then, the chemical variables are static, meaning that they don't change over time.

Here some examples of what I see could potentially be possible (and which don't give an error):

```
m1<-lmer(sqrt(co2)~t.air+t.soil+ph+treatment+TC+TN+Fe+(1|site), data=data, na.action=na.exclude)
```

```
m2<-lmer(sqrt(co2)~t.air+t.soil+ph+TC+TN+Fe+(1|treatment/site), data=data, na.action=na.exclude)
```

```
m3<-lmer(sqrt(co2)~t.air+t.soil+ph+treatment+TC+TN+Fe+(1|date/site), data=data, na.action=na.exclude)
```

I am actually most concerned about getting the potential interaction between treatment:site and the fixed environmental/chemical effects included in the model. However, our institute has now for a while been without statistician, so there is no help to expect.

The data looks like that:

| date | treatment | site | t.soil | t.air | ph | TN | TC | Fe | wtd | co2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21/06/2019 | 1 | LV | 15.55 | 15.14 | 4.55 | 1.43 | 46.79 | 1.47 | 40.5 | 523.53 |
| 05/07/2019 | 1 | LV | 14.12 | 20.14 | 4.55 | 1.43 | 46.79 | 1.47 | 38.5 | 408.53 |
| etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. |
| 21/06/2019 | 2 | LV | 15.66 | 12.74 | 4.55 | 1.43 | 46.79 | 1.47 | 4.5 | 225.77 |
| 05/07/2019 | 2 | LV | 13.88 | 17.16 | 4.55 | 1.43 | 46.79 | 1.47 | 4.4 | 243.74 |
| etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. |

There are 5 sites, 2 treatments, 25 sampling campaigns = 250 observations in total

Comment: You don't really have enough sites to fit random effects. You can do it, but it is very questionable.

Comment: Hi Robert, so 5 sites with 4 replicates each is really not enough? What else would you suggest?

Comment: You can fit fixed effects for site